# Strong dependence of a chart

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, general-relativity

I am listening to a differential geometry lecture this semester, after the Definition of the Christoffel symbols of a connection $\nabla$ it says that

> [...] the first term is strongly dependent on the chart.

in regards to the formula

$$\nabla_XY = \sum_k \bigg( \sum_i X_i \dfrac{\partial Y_k}{\partial x_i} + \sum_{ij} X_i Y_j\Gamma_{ij}^k
\bigg) \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_k}$$

for a chart $(U, \varphi = (x_1, \ldots, x_n))$ of a smooth Manifold $M$ and two vectorfields
$$X = \sum_i X_i \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\quad \text{and}\quad Y = \sum_j Y_j \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}.$$

How can I see that there is a "strong dependence" or rather, what does it mean to be strongly dependent on a chart?

Comment: This seems like an odd thing to say... *everything* in this equation is "strongly dependent" on the chart.

Comment: The adjective "strongly" isn't meant in any technical sense. They're just trying to emphasize something like "hey, look at this! This term depends very much on the choice of chart". Though, I agree with the above comment; everything in this equation, $X_i,Y_j,\Gamma^j_{i,j}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$ are all objects obtained from a chart.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up.

Comment: Well I do not disagree with  the above comments, but as an exercise try to compute how these objects transform when you change the chart. You will notice, the Christoffel  symbols transform differently and "one needs more information about the chart" ( that as well is not meant in a technical sense)

Comment: I think that the comment is meant to point out that the first term by itself cannot be used to define a derivative operator.